# Why am I getting an error while breaking a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate a code which will give me a drop-down list for my spreadsheet. I have a formula which is long and I tried to use breaks as was shown in various communities but somehow the formula is not working. I am new to VBA coding and below is what I was able to do.
Help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Sub Trial()
'
' Trial Macro
'

'
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "= If _ 
    ("IF($B$57=Sheet1!$N$17,Sheet1!N18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$O$17,Sheet1!O18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$P$17,Sheet1!P18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$Q$17,Sheet1!Q18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$R$17,Sheet1!R18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$S$17,Sheet1!S18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$T$17,Sheet1!T18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$U$17,Sheet1!U18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$V$17,Sheet1!V18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$W$17,Sheet1!W18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$X$17,Sheet1!X18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$Y$17,Sheet1!Y18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$Z$17,Sheet1!Z18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AA$17,Sheet1!AA18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AB$17,Sheet1!AB18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AC$17,Sheet1!AC18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AD$17,Sheet1!AD18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AE$17,Sheet1!AE18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AF$17,Sheet1!AF18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AG$17,Sheet1!AG18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AH$17,Sheet1!AH18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AI$17,Sheet1!AI18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AJ$17,Sheet1!AJ18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AK$17,Sheet1!AK18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AL$17,Sheet1!AL18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AM$17,Sheet1!AM18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AN$17,Sheet1!AN18,IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AO$17,Sheet1!AO18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AP$17,Sheet1!AP18, _
    IF($B$57=Sheet1!$AQ$17,Sheet1!AQ18,"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) = ""Mixer_11"","""")"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to put the `_` outside the quotes and concatenate so change the `_` to `" & _`

Comment: BTW you can replace that long formula with INDEX/MATCH: `"=IF(INDEX(N18:AQ18,MATCH($B$57,$N$17:$AQ$17,0))=""Mixer_11"","""",FALSE)"`

Comment: All due respect, but I would suggest deleting this mess altogether and starting anew. This code is incomprehensible and very hard to maintain.

Comment: A better solution than that enormous mountain of IF statements would to use a SWITCH/CASE  https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Comment: @ScottCraner Hi Scott, thank you for the advice. The problem with Index match is that the Range N18 to AQ17 is a whole table with the match B57 being the header of that table. I am trying to populate the columns when I select the header name from a different drop down list. I hope I am making sense! I will try the " & _ solution and get back to you!

Comment: @ScottCraner Hello Scott, I tried the & variation and it works. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @FrankBall Hello Frank, I am trying your solution to check if it will clean my code further and reduce the hard coded portion of the code. Thank you for the suggestion.